# Boolean Algebra: Prove associate law for products

Tags: proof-writing, boolean-algebra, associativity

I'm working through some old papers for an exam coming up, and I found this question that I cannot seem to answer, and I don't have the memos.

Could someone please help me out?

The question:
Prove the associative law for products: For any elements a, b, and c in a Boolean
algebra,
$$(a ∗ b) ∗ c = a ∗ (b ∗ c).$$
Begin your proof by letting $L = (a ∗ b) ∗ c$ and
$R = a ∗ (b ∗ c)$, and first show that $a + L = a + R$, and then that $a′ + L = a′ + R$.
You may only use the axioms of Definition 1.2, and then also idempotency, boundedness, and absorption.

And Definition 1.2:

> Commutativity:
> $a+b=b+a$
> $a*b=b*a$
>
> Distributivity:
> $a + (b ∗ c) = (a + b) ∗ (a + c)$
> $a ∗ (b + c) = (a ∗ b) + (a ∗ c)$
>
> Identities:
> $a + 0 = a$
> $a * 1 = a$
>
> Complements:
> $a + a' = 1$
> $a *a' = 0$

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Mathjax please, this hurts the eyes

Answer (score 2):

Let us calculate those terms:

\begin{align}
a + L
&= a + ( (a * b) * c )\\
&= (a + (a * b)) * (a + c)\tag{distributivity}\\
&= a * (a + c)\tag{absortion}\\
&= a.\tag{absortion}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a + R &= a + ( a * (b*c) )\\
&= a. \tag{absortion}  
\end{align}
Thus, $a+L=a+R$.

\begin{align}
a' + R
&= a'+ (a * (b*c))\\
&= (a' + a) * (a' + (b*c))\tag{distributivity}\\
&= 1 * ((a' + b) * (a' + c))\tag{distributivity, complement}\\
&= (a' + b) * (a' + c).\tag{identities}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a' + L
&= a' + ((a*b)*c)\\
&= (a' + (a*b)) * (a' + c)\tag{distributivity}\\
&= ((a' + a) * (a' + b))*(a' + c)\tag{distributivity}\\
&= ( 1 * (a' + b) ) * (a' + c)\tag{complement}\\
&= (a' + b) * (a' + c),
\end{align}
and so $a' + R = a' +L$.

Now given that $a+L=a+R$ and $a' + R = a' +L$,

\begin{align}
L
&= (a * a') + L \\
&= (a + L) * (a' + L)  \\
&= (a + R) * (a' + R)\\
&= (a * a') + R\\
&= R,
\end{align}
where by now, I suppose you can justify the above equalities.